# Scala syntax for polymorphism in val functions

Tags: scala, generics, syntax, functional-programming, polymorphism

This is potentially super easy, but I can't find any documentation on my problem.
There are two ways to define a functions in Scala, one with the `def` and the other with the `val` keyword. As an adept in functional programming, I'd like to use the latter more.

Now I have a problem: It's no problem to write a `def` function with a polymorphic type parameter:

```scala
def function[T](n: T) = {print(n)} // syntactically fine
```

How to do the same thing with the `val` keyword still eludes me though. This naive approach is syntactically invalid:

```scala
val function[T]: (a: T) => print(a) // Doesn't compile
```

That said, it is absolutely possible that I misunderstand Scala's approach on polymorphism and generics here.

Comment: Actually the first statement is wrong, `def` creates **methods**, not **functions**. And actually what you asked is a [FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html) search there for "difference between functions and methods"_ - TL;DR; what you want is not possible in **Scala 2** but will be in **Scala 3**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala 2 it is impossible to define parametric function, only method.

In Scala 3 [polymorphic function type](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html) is introduced:

```
val fun: [A] => A => Unit = [A] => a => println(a.toString)
```

Workaround used in 2 by Cats and friends were traits with polymorphic `apply`

```
trait MySpecialFunctionlikeThing {
  def apply[A](a: A): Unit
}
```

Unfortunately, single abstract method (SAM) doesn't work with things like that, so some tricks were used to make it easy to lift function into such methods:

```
object MySpecialFunctionlikeThing {

  type Arbitrary

  def lift(f: Arbitrary => Unit): MySpecialFunctionlikeThing =
    new MySpecialFunctionlikeThing {
      def apply[A](a: A): Unit = f(a.asInstanceOf[Arbitrary])
    }
}

val fun = MySpecialFunctionlikeThing.lift(a => println(a))
```

The latter I saw in several different forms: the above, one using existential types and one using one of the above for method signature and macro for implementation (see [`FunctionK.lift`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/8e8be51187385dde78321e7e0d9fd892801afacb/core/src/main/scala-2.x/src/main/scala/cats/arrow/FunctionKMacros.scala#L29)).

Quite often, though, you can get away with what you used that is parametric, nullary method returning non-parametric function.

```
def fun[A]: A => Unit = a => println(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would require higher-rank types, which isn't supported in Scala 2.

It is supported in Scala 3:
https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html